# Why can't I query correctly against a HashMap field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch v1.5.2. I have a JSON document that looks like the following.

```
{
    "id": "RRRZe32",
    "metadata": {
        "published": "2010-07-29T18:11:43.000Z",
        "codeId": "AChdUxnsuRyoCo7roK6gqZSg",
        "codeTitle": "something"
    }
}
```

My Java POJO object that backs this JSON looks like the following. Note that I am using Spring-Boot v1.3.0.M2 with `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` dependency.

```
@Document(indexName="ws", type="vid")
public class Video {
 @Id 
 private String id;


 @Field(type=FieldType.Object, index=FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
 private Map<String, Object> metadata;
}
```

My mapping is defined as follows.

```
{
    "ws": {
        "mappings": {
            "vid": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "metadata": {
                        "properties": {
                            "codeId": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "codeTitle": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can query the document (using `Sense`) successfully by `metadata.codeTitle` but not `metadata.codeId`. My query for `metadata.codeTitle` looks like the following.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "metadata.codeTitle": {
                            "value": "something"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My query for `metadata.codeId` looks like the following.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "metadata.codeId": {
                            "value": "AChdUxnsuRyoCo7roK6gqZSg"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your `codeId` field is `analyzed` and the value is lowercased at indexing time. So you have two solutions:

You can query like this (i.e. all lowercase)

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "metadata.codeId": {
                            "value": "achduxnsuryoco7rok6gqzsg"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can declare your `codeId` field as `not_analyzed` and keep your query as it is.

In your case, it looks like case 1 will be easier to implement.

Comment: Yes, that's the answer. But if you noticed, using Spring's annotations, I thought I did specify `not_analyzed` with `FieldIndex.not_analyzed`. I'll accept your answer in a bit (SO wants me to wait 8 minutes).

Comment: The `not_analyzed` you've specified is for the `metadata` field and that doesn't cascade down to the inner fields of `metadata`. You can see it when retrieving the generated mapping for your `vid` type with `curl -XGET localhost:9200/ws/_mapping/vid`