# Spring Elasticsearch HashMap[String, String] mapping value cannot be not_analyzed

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, hashmap, spring-data-elasticsearch

Actually my question is very simple: I want my hashmap value not_analyzed!

Now i have one object contains a hashmap[string, string], looks like:

```
class SomeObject{
    String id;
    @Field(type=FieldType.Object, index=FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
    Map<String, String> parameters;
}
```

then Spring data elasticsearch generate the mapping like this at the beggining:

```
{
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "type": "object"
    }
}
```

then after i add some objects to the es, it add more attributes like this:

```
{
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "properties": {
             "shiduan": {
                "type": "string"
             },
             "季节": {
                "type": "string"
             }
        }
    }
}
```

now, because of the parameters's value is analyzed, so cannot be search by es, i mean cannot search chinese value, i have tried i can search english at this time.

THEN, AFTER READ THIS POST https://stackoverflow.com/a/32044370/4148034, I UPDATE THE MAPPING MANUALLY TO THIS:

```
{
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "properties": {
             "shiduan": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
             },
             "季节": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
             }
        }
    }
}
```

I CAN SEARCH CHINESE NOW, SO I KNOW THE PROBLEM IS "not_analyzed", LIKE THE POST SAID.

Finally, anyone can tell me how to make the map value "not_analyzed", i had google and stackoverflow many many times still cannot find the answer, let me know if someone can help, thanks very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to create a `mappings.json` file on your build path (e.g. `yourproject/src/main/resources/mappings`) and then reference that mapping using the `@Mapping` annotation in your class.

```
@Document(indexName = "your_index", type = "your_type")
@Mapping(mappingPath = "/mappings/mappings.json")
public class SomeObject{
    String id;
    @Field(type=FieldType.Object, index=FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
    Map<String, String> parameters;
}
```

In that mapping file, we're going to add a [dynamic template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) which will target the subfields of your `parameters` hashmap and declare them to be `not_analyzed` string.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "path_match": "parameters.*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You need to make sure to delete `your_index` first and then restart your application so it can be recreated with the proper mapping.

Comment: Sorry for not accept your answer on time, it works. Thanks again for your help 

Comment: @val Is there a newer approach to this or do I still have to do it this way? Thanks for your prev. answer ;)

Comment: @FabianTe not that I know of even though there was [this PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/132) but it never got merged